# CNN multioutput regression architecture modification

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, deep-neural-networks, regression

I am working on a regression task where the model has to predict two values at the same time. The idea is that the dataset consists of 16 features, where the first 8 features represent the first value that the model needs to predict and the next 8 features represent the second position. How should I go about doing this and adapt my model? Initially the model predicted just one single value from a dataset of 8 features

This is how one row of the data set looks like for example:

0,003345971 0,003345971 0,003345971 0,003345971 0,003345971 0,003346    0,003346    0,003346    0,003525485 0,00445148  0,00349107  0,00417936  0,00370763  0,00390843  0,00400138  0,00362335

This is how part of the output file looks like, The two columns are the same

| First column | Second column |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0.002 | 0.002 |
| 0.004 | 0.004 |
| 0.006 | 0.006 |
| 0.008 | 0.008 |
| 0.01 | 0.01 |
| 0.012 | 0.012 |

This is how the model architecture for predicting one single value looks like

```
def build_model(n_steps, n_features):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, input_shape=(n_steps, n_features), padding='Same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding='Same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

    model.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, padding='Same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, padding='Same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

    model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, padding='Same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, padding='Same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, padding='Same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))


    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1096, activation='relu'))

    model.add(Dense(1))

    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.0005)

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
    return model
```

This is how I train the model and the callbacks used. Using EarlyStopping does not seem to make the model better

```
def train_model(model, x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, batch_size):
    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=100, verbose=1)
    learning_rate_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, verbose=1, factor=0.5, min_lr=0.00001)

    log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    tensorboard_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

    history = model.fit(
        x_train, y_train, epochs=1000,
        verbose=1,
        validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
        callbacks=[learning_rate_reduction, early_stopping],
        batch_size=batch_size
    )

    avg_mae = np.mean(history.history['mae'])
    print(f"Average MAE: {avg_mae}")

    plot_history(history)

    # return history
    return history, history.history['val_mae'], history.history['val_loss']
```

This is the function that splits the data

````
def split_data(idata, odata):
    x = idata.iloc[:, 0:].values
    y = odata.iloc[:, np.r_[0, 1]].values


    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

    return np.asarray(x_train).astype(np.float32), np.asarray(y_train).astype(np.float32), np.asarray(x_test).astype(
        np.float32), np.asarray(y_test).astype(np.float32)
```
````